# Why gunicorn fails to find attribute in the py file?

Tags: python, gunicorn

I have a `dashboard.py` file containing the code below:

```
    def run_explainer_dashboard(
    bucket_name: str,
    blob_dashboard_config: str,
    explainer_path: Union[str, "PathLike[str]"]
) -> ExplainerDashboard:
    ...
    return dashboard

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from a.settings import (
        BLOB_DASHBOARD_CONFIG,
        BUCKET_NAME
    )

    dashboard = run_explainer_dashboard(
        bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
        blob_dashboard_config='dashboard.yaml',
        explainer_path="...",
    )

    dashboard.run(
        host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)), use_waitress=True
    )
```

When I run `gunicorn` to run `dashboard.py` using the code below:
`gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8080 --chdir ~/.../src dashboard:dashboard --timeout 0`, I got an error message saying:

> Failed to find attribute 'dashboard' in 'dashboard'.

If I remove the `if __name__ == "__main__":`, then the `gunicorn` works.

Why is that so?

How do I use the `gunicorn` command if I want to keep the `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

Comment: There is no global `dashboard` in your file after import, or at least not the part that you shared with us. I can only see a presumed local variable called `dashboard` in `run_explainer_dashboard` and a variable called `dashboard` that only gets created if the module is run as main, which is not what gunicorn does.

Comment: "Why is that so?" Because `__name__` is no longer equal to `'__main__'`. "How do I use the gunicorn command if I want to keep the `if __name__ == "__main__":`?" You don't; redesign the code so that it doesn't matter.

Comment: For example, you can create a function named `main`, and use that for the entry point on the `gunicorn` command line, and also have it called from the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. Make sure that it has the correct parameters according to what gunicorn expects.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, would you mind to show your example above as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```python
from a.settings import (
        BLOB_DASHBOARD_CONFIG,
        BUCKET_NAME
    )

def run_explainer_dashboard(
    bucket_name: str,
    blob_dashboard_config: str,
    explainer_path: Union[str, "PathLike[str]"]
) -> ExplainerDashboard:
    ...
    return dashboard

dashboard = run_explainer_dashboard(
        bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
        blob_dashboard_config='dashboard.yaml',
        explainer_path="...",
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dashboard.run(
        host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)), use_waitress=True
    )
```